# How can I 'swap' react for react/addons in my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

I want to use the Perf stuff. It seems that if I do:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
```

in my own modules then libraries (react-bootstrap, react-router etc.) end up using another copy of plain react and things break. I am using browserify.

Is there a fix or another way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at creating a browserify shim for the React w/ addons, that way every file which requires an instance of React will get the version you tell it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my gulpfile. Tx for the comments about looking for a browserify shim that lead me to the solution:

My browserify task (from [React JS workflow, part 2](http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/10/30/react-js-workflow-part2.html)) builds separate vendors.js (libs) and main.js (my app) bundles during development using browserify.external(..) to exclude the libs from main.js. I just had to add "react/addons" as an external lib along with "react".

The issue is explained here:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1161

Answer (score 0):

Requiring `react` and `react/addons` will give you the same object. `react/addons` requires the same module that `react` does (`lib/React`), and `react/addons` even mutates that object so that anyone requiring `react` will get the addons as well.

If you end up with multiple versions of React in your bundle, it's because the libraries you use have `react` as a dependency instead of a peer dependency. You should use `npm dedupe` to avoid that. But `react-router` has `react` as a peer dependency, so `react-router` will get the same `react` module instance as your module (with the addons). Don't know about the other packages you use that depend on React though.

Comment: I checked all the libs and they all have it as a peerDependency. I have since figured out the problem after reviewing comments here. About to post answer.